# Getting data into a uint8_t array (C/C++) on Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, lora

I'm working in C/C++ on Arduino and am having trouble getting what I need into an array of type uint8_t. C/C++ is not a language I'm familiar with (I'm a python / php / basic guy), so I'm struggling with finding the right terms / docs at the moment.

Basically, the following is show in an example, and works:

```
static uint8_t mydata[] = "Hello";
```

I would later like to completely replace the contents of this with something else.

```
String Temp = "31.0";
String Hum = "60.0";
String Measurements = "";

Measurements = Temp + "C" + Hum + "H";
mydata[0] = ""; //Reset the array contents? Not sure.
uint8_t mydata[] = Measurements;
```

The above code example results in the following error from the compiler:

```
error: initializer fails to determine size of 'mydata'
uint8_t mydata[] = Measurements;
        ^~~~~~

error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
uint8_t mydata[] = Measurements;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~

initializer fails to determine size of 'mydata'
```

Any suggestions on how I can deal with this? The first instance where I see `static uint8_t mydata[] = "Hello";` being used does not require the declaration of a size of the data. If I change to `uint8_t mydata[0] = Measurements;` then the length warning goes away, but I'm left with the message that an array must be initialised with a brace-enclosed initialiser.

Comment: You can't assign to whole arrays in C++. You can only assign elements individually, using a loop or one of the standard library functions such as `std::copy` or `std::strncpy`.

Comment: Did I kind of get to the right point with the ```uint8_t mydata[0] = Measurements;``` approach? That way I'm assigning to array element 0.

Comment: @anakaine No, `uint8_t mydata[0] = Measurements;` isn't valid c++. You aren't allowed to declare an array of size `0` and you certainly wouldn't be allowed to assign something to an array of size `0` (if it was allowed to exist).

Comment: I think you'd better use `String` instead of `uint8_t[]` everywhere in the code you've shown. Arrays have fixed sizes in c++ (VLA:s may be allowed by the arduino gcc compiler - but I would stay away from those).

Comment: I'm reasonably sure I can't use String. The next step is that mydata[] gets loaded into a function that sends the message out from a radio module. The module and subsequent network expects payloads in a particular format. I'm sticking as close as I can to the example for the moment.

Comment: Ok,  if it isn't too big you could post your whole sketch and point out what you're trying to do. You are currently not using arrays properly. Have you installed [ArduinoSTL](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/arduino-stl)? It's a version of the C++ standard library (although not complete) that contains a lot of classes and functions that helps you to write better, safer and more efficient code.

Comment: You need to learn about C strings, use the crappy and bloated Arduino String class, or stick with python.

Comment: Trying to do the former, Tom. I'd hate to only ever know about one thing and remain underinformed. Part of being a learner is knowing when to ask for help from the more experienced. So, you know, thanks for the help and the snark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For embedded code, compactness is the key. Use user-defined structure like so.

```
struct Temperature{
  uint8_t temp[7];
  uint8_t humi[7];
  Temperature(){temp[0] = humi[0] ='\0';}
  Temperature(uint8_t * t, uint8_t *h){strcpy(temp,t); strcpy(humi,h);}
  void reset(){ temp[0] = humi[0] ='\0';}  
  void setTemp(uint8_t* t){strcpy(temp,t);}
  void setHum(uint8_t* h){strcpy(humi,h);}
  void print(){ char str[16]; sprintf(str,"Temp=%4.2f Hum=%4.2f", atof(temp), atof(humi)); Serial.println(str);}
  void operator=(Temperature other){ strcpy(temp,other.temp); strcpy(humi,other.humi);}
};    

void loop() {
  Temperature temp1;
  temp1.reset();
  temp1.setTemp("52.34");
  temp1.setHum("30");
  Temperature temp2;
  temp2 = temp1;
  temp2.print();
}
```

Comment: There's stuff going on in that code snippet that I can't get to compile in C or C++.

Comment: @user4581301 gotta be C because this is C++ legal. Remember though this is Arduino C++.

Comment: We have constructors and similar, so C is definitely out, but there must be exceptions in place that disable a lot of type safety..